# insert MySQL row on page load

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, insert, pageload

This is going to be my first question on stackoverflow so I hope I'm doing it right =)

I want to insert a MySQL record when the **page loads**.
I have a form and a database. I want to be able to see in my database if the user has visited the form page( obviously without submitting the form ).
I know how to do it on page submit, but how can I fill up a MySQL row on page load?

Example of my wish:
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EeuSi.png)

I'm very curious how this can be done . Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show us what you have tried

Comment: You should really start with pretty much any introductory tutorial on PHP and MySQL.  Inserting a record into the database will be covered by any such tutorial.

Comment: I haven't really tried anything because I have no idea how/where to start. I've been googling for a while but couldn't find any answer specific to my question. The form I have now is working fine and inserts the needed rows on submit.

@David I know how inserting rows ( also with PDO ) works. but Im not sure wether it can be done with jquery/javascript or something very simple as in html body onload.

Comment: @MasoumiProjects so what is your question? show us an example of what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Specifically: how to insert records on a pageload ( before even submitting it ). All it needs to do is insert 1 record ( wether the user has viewed the page already or not )

Comment: @MasoumiProjects: You can make an AJAX request from JavaScript when the page loads.  But why?  If you're loading the page from the server then why not perform your server-side logic at that time?  Why wait until the page loads in the browser and then send a *second* request to the server?  Have you tried just simply... executing an `INSERT` statement in your code?

Comment: The reason is that I want to see if the user has viewed the page , but hasnt filled it yet. The user is logged in, So i have his ID / credentials. ( with php session ). If I see that a user has viewed the form, but has not filled it, I want to be able to see that in database so I can contact them to help them with the form.

Comment: Then @David's logic is still valid. You can still execute `INSERT` when all your code gets executed.

Comment: I assume your insert code (that is working) is wrapped in an if, copy this code, remove the if, tweak the sql, job done?!

Comment: @MasoumiProjects: Ok, so what's the problem?  What is preventing you from executing an `INSERT` statement in your PHP code for that page?  If you need examples of how to perform an `INSERT`, any tutorial will cover that.  What happens when you ***try*** to execute an `INSERT` statement in your code?

Comment: @David The insert is working just fine ( when user clicks on submit). What I want is the page to silently insert record on page load without the user noticing it. ( that way I can know if a user has visited the form, but hasnt submitted it )

Comment: example:    if(page loads){
insert into table that user has viewed the page
}

Comment: @Azzazzell: I really don't know how else to explain this... If you have working code for inserting a record into a database and you want to execute that code in that page then *put the code in the page*.  Any PHP code you add to that page *will be executed* when the page is requested by the browser.  So if you want to execute an `INSERT` operation in code, then add an `INSERT` operation to your code.  We can't reach into your computer and type it for you, you have to at least *try* yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use AJAX for this kind of stuff..

update.php

```
<?php
    mysqli_query("INSERT INTO bla (column1, column2) VALUES (value1, value2)") or die(mysqli_error());
```

?>

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "update.php"
        success: function(data) {
            // success
        }
    });
});
```

**This is a really basic way, you could use "$_GET" to send data in your AJAX request etc.**

-

**Edit: @David had a fair point in the comments. Try that first.**

Comment: Thanks... This is exactly what I needed!  I had a feeling that it can be done with jquery document ready function, but not how it can be done exactly:)